# php files upload (image and flash files) issue

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

As I am working on a file uploading task I have used jQuery and php for uploading files to server for reducing the number of http requests. From the admin control panel everything is fine except the file uploading.  The file uploading is working properly in localhost but when I am working on this in the live server environment the files are not getting uploaded.  Ihave changed the file permissions to 0777.

The strange thing permissions are automatically changed to 755 after you set it to 777 or after you upload the game.

Actually the process is:
- I am storing both the files i.e, image and .swf file in one directory
- The directory gets created with its database table id
- The game file and game image are not getting uploaded in that corresponding directory

For example, the game id 342 gets created with a directory name called 342 but image and swf file are not getting uploaded in that directory.  For every game the corresponding directory gets created with the game id.

My code: 
file name : uploadify.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
        $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
        $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
        $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
        $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

            mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            chmod($targetFile,0777);
            echo "1";

    }
```

jQuery file : js.js

```
$('#fileinput').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'uploader/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploader/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'uploader/cancel.png',
        'auto'      : true,
        'folder'    : "../../../games/"+$("#newgameid").val()+"/",
        'onComplete' : function(event,queueID,fileObj){
            $("#flashfileupload").html("file<strong>: "+ fileObj.name + " ("+ Math.round(fileObj.size/1000) + " kb)</strong> has been uploaded successfully!");    
            $("#size").val(Math.round(fileObj.size/1000));
            $("#filename").val(fileObj.name);
            $("#submitgame").removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        'onOpen' : function(event,queueID,fileObj){
            if(fileObj.name.indexOf(".swf")==-1){
                alert('Error Input - Flash game must SWF File!')
                $('#fileinput').uploadifyClearQueue();
            }
        }


    });


    $('#thumnail').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'uploader/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploader/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'uploader/cancel.png',
        'auto'      : true,
        'folder'    : "../../../games/"+$("#newgameid").val()+"/",
        'onComplete' : function(event,queueID,fileObj){
            $("#thumnailfileupload").html("file<strong>: "+ fileObj.name + " ("+ Math.round(fileObj.size/1000) + " kb)</strong> has been uploaded successfully!");
            $("#thumbnail").val(fileObj.name);
        }

    });
```

Please help me in this regard. Thanks for your time on reading this issue. Any suggestions are accepted.

Regards,
phphunger.

Answer (score 0):

Your mkdir() function call is setting the permissions to 0755:

```
mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
```

Try setting it to 777:

```
mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0777, true);
```

Comment: hi londons, thanks for your reply. i have changed it but the folder gets created but no image and flash content in it rather the folder permissions remain 0755. even if i tried to change it to 0777 changes are not applied to it. even i am unable to upload the files manually also..

Comment: As a sanity check, have you made sure your php.ini allows uploads of the size you're trying?  Any debug output for $_FILES or $targetFile you could show?

Comment: Actually the process works fine in localhost but problem in ftp upload. Anyhow i have a .htaccess file in that see the may be the following code restricts not to upload the files. The code is php_value post_max_size 80M
php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
php_value max_execution_time 120

Comment: Can you make sure your php file is owned by a user that can set 777 permissions on a new folder?  It sounds like a configuration/permissions issue before a code issue.

Comment: Means i didn't get you. What do you mean by setting 777 permissions on a new folder? Actually i have set the folder to 777 but its automatically changes back to 755 the folder which is created newly.

Comment: yes landons you said right. its the configuration issue rather than code issue. so could you please tell me how can i make the php file to set the folder permissions to 777.

Comment: Try changing your mkdir() call above to 0777 (rather than 0755), and then TEMPORARILY change your php file permissions to 777 too.  Check if it works as you expect, and then we'll go from there...